# Rotate animation is not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml, rotation, android-animation

I need to implement a 'Rotate' animation to a `TextView`. Following is the code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView words;
    private Map<String, String> wordsMap;
    private Animation rotate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        words = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word);

        rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);

        wordsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        wordsMap.put("Dog", "Perro");
        wordsMap.put("Cat", "Gato");
        wordsMap.put("Universe", "Universo");
        wordsMap.put("Telephone", "Teléfono");
        wordsMap.put("Key Board", "Teclado Del");
        wordsMap.put("Country", "País");

        //Registering Listeners
        words.setOnClickListener(new TextClicked());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private OnTouchListener textViewSwiped = new OnSwipeTouchListener()
    {
        public boolean onSwipeLeft() 
         {
            return true;
         }
    };

    private class TextClicked implements OnClickListener
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            words.setAnimation(rotate);
                    words.setText("Rotated");

        }

    }

}
```

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="600"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

When I click on the `TextView`, it doesn't work. Apart from that, the rotate animation I need is bit different than what I have done here. This rotation is like a circle. What I need is something which turns upside down and display the new text. For an example, you can flip a Card in a play card set to show the other side right? I need the same thing.

**UPDATE**

I am not seeking for a 90 degree rotation. It should be like how you can "flip" a card (I am talking about real cards in card play sets) to the other side.

Comment: @pskink:I am not seeking for a 90 degree rotation. It should be like how you can "flip" a card (I am talking about real cards in card play sets) to the other side.

Answer (score 1):

"What I need is something which turns upside down and display the new text...."

for that, you need to use [ObjectAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html) which supports from API 11 and you can download supprort library for this from [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids).

and see the sample code which rotates TextView along Y-axis...

```
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "rotationY", 0,90,180,270,360);
    animator.setDuration(3000);
    animator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    animator.start();
```

Comment: Hello, this animation simply "blinks" isnt it?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "blinks", but it rotates TextView along Y-axis along center_horizontal line

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="90" // changable
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="600"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

Comment: I am not seeking for a 90 degree rotation. It should be like how you can "flip" a card (I am talking about real cards in card play sets) to the other side.

Answer (score 1):

Chnage your xml code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<rotate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
     android:toDegrees="90"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%" />

</set>
```

and also on textview click start the animation

```
words.startAnimation(rotate);
words.setText("Rotated");
```

Animation listener in `onCreate()`

```
rotate.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            words.setText("Rotated");
        }
    });
```

Comment: and you can change the text after animation completed,for this you can use listener

Comment: you can change the from degree and todegree attibutes according to your need.

Comment: I am not seeking for a 90 degree rotation. It should be like how you can "flip" a card (I am talking about real cards in card play sets) to the other side.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for this. Here it is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<scale

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

       android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"

       android:pivotX="50%"

       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"

       android:pivotY="50%"

       android:duration="250" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public class FlipAnimation extends Animation {
    private View view;
    private Drawable drawable;
    private boolean backSide;
    private Camera camera;

    public FlipAnimation(View v, Drawable d) {
        this.view = v;
        this.drawable = d; // this needs to be a mirrored Drawable
        this.camera = new Camera();
        this.camera.save();
        this.backSide = false;
        setDuration(3000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        float degrees = 180 * interpolatedTime;
        if (degrees > 90 && !backSide) {
            backSide = true;
            view.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        }
        camera.restore();
        camera.save();
        camera.rotateX(degrees);
        Matrix m = t.getMatrix();
        camera.getMatrix(m);
        float w2 = view.getWidth() / 2f;
        float h2 = view.getHeight() / 2f;
        m.preTranslate(-w2, -h2);
        m.postTranslate(w2, h2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an anim folder in res. and add the .xml file,name it `from_middle` and paste the following code

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromXScale="0.0" android:toXScale="1.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="250" />
```

Make another xml file and name it `to_middle` and paste the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<scale

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromXScale="1.0" android:toXScale="0.0"
       android:pivotX="50%"
       android:fromYScale="1.0" android:toYScale="1.0"
       android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="250" />
```

In your activity:

paste this code onCreate:

```
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.to_middle);
    animation1.setAnimationListener(this);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.from_middle);
    animation2.setAnimationListener(this);
```

and onAnimationEnd:

```
@Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
         if (animation==animation1) {
             if (isBackOfCardShowing) { // boolean variable
             mtextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.surfboard_memory);

               } else {
             mtextView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_memory);// any pic
               }
             mtextView1.clearAnimation();
             mtextView1.setAnimation(animation2);
             mtextView1.startAnimation(animation2);
         } else {
                isBackOfCardShowing=!isBackOfCardShowing;
                mtextView1.setEnabled(true);
         }
    }
```

It actually works and is tested..:)